# ¿Como quitar la configuración SSL de un proyecto .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Saludos he creado un proyecto en .NET Core y he seleccionado la opción de HTTPS, ahora cada vez que ejecuto el proyecto este me redirige a una url con HTTPS, en el program he puesto el siguiente código:

```cs
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                    
                    .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
                    .UseUrls("http://localhost:44326/", "http://192.168.1.238:44326/")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>().UseEnvironment("Development")
                    .UseKestrel(x => {
                        x.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 44326);
                        x.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.238"), 44326);
                    });
        }
```

Tambien he modificado el *launchsettings.json* del proyecto, donde tambien probe modificar las url:

```
 "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
```

Tambien desactive la opción del Startup.cs :

```cs
 // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Tambien intente la opcion de eliminar HTST de chrome usando esto: "chrome://net-internals/#hsts"
**Lo que deseo es poder desactivar esta opción o la redirección de *http* a *https* ya que siempre que ingreso la url que he configurado me lleva a una con HTTPS, en todos los navegadores.**

Comment: ¿Has intentado retirar lo que hay dentro de `UseKestrel` ?

Comment: como es que ingresas ? o sea, cuando ejecutas desde el VS o cuando publicas en el IIS o en algun hosting

Comment: @LeandroTuttini lo ejecuto desde el VS e ingreso a la url que le configure

Answer (score 1):

En las propiedades de tu proyecto, en la pestaña de **Depurar/Debug** tienes que desmarcar la casilla **"Habilitar SSL"**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola ya esta deshabilitado esa opción

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner en el launchsettings.json la url así? "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000". El puerto es importante.

Comment: Si señor lo he probado

Answer (score 0):

en el archivo

```
launchSettings.json
```

dentro del nodo de iisexpress debes agregar

```
"sslPort": 0
```

Comment: Hola @LeonardoChavez, ¿qué es lo que hace `"sslPort": 0`?